# Postprocess *.js files with grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I am wondering of there is any possibility of postprocessing *.js files so that every gsp expression can be evaluated.

for example i can write the following code directly in the gsp page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.post("${createLink(controller:'mycontroller',action:'myaction')} " , {"id":id},function(){});
</script>
```

And the expression ${createLink} is evaluated by grails.

But i would like to also use ${createLink()} in *.js files which are not processed by grails.
Maybe it is possible to use the resource plugin to postprocess every *.js file and evaluate gsp expressions?

Of course i could wrap all my js code in a separate gsp page but it does not seem like an elegant solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of this should work for you

- http://grails.org/plugin/gsp-arse (standalone)
- http://grails.org/plugin/gsp-resources (It works with resources plugin)

Comment: Thank you. The GSP resources plugin was exacly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do something similar to store the url in a variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var url = "${createLink(controller:'mycontroller',action:'myaction')}";
</script>
```

Then you can use all the ajax calls you want and still only have the url set once.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JS Hash in your GSP file to save what matters

```
<r:script>
 var linkobject={
   mylink:'${createLink(controller:"mycontroller",action:"myaction")}',
     linkA : '${params.id}',
    linkB: '${g.createLink(action: "getThreats")}',
    linkC: '${g.createLink(action: "addThreat")}',
    linkD: '${g.resource(dir: 'images/icons', file: 'folder.png')}'
 
}

</r:script>
```

Then,  Consume that JS hash in your JavaScript file to get what you need:

```
$.post(linkobject.mylink , {"id":linkobject.linkA},function(){});
```